# How to pass a pointer argument to std::format?

Tags: c++, formatting, std, c++20

In the following code, when the first argument is an `int` and another a pointer casted to `void*`, the code compiles:

```
AYAPI_API int AYBlitBuffer(int a1, int a2, int* a3, int* a4)
{
    Log(std::format("@{}: a1 = {}, a2 = {}, a3 = {}, a4 = {}", __FUNCTION__, a1, a2, static_cast<void*>(a3), static_cast<void*>(a4)));
    return 0;
}
```

If, however, passing a unique argument that is a pointer, the code does not compile:

```
AYAPI_API int AYRenderPrim(int *a1)
{
    Log(std::format("@{}: a1 = {:#010x}", __FUNCTION__, static_cast<void*>(a1)));
    return 0;
}
```

The actual error:

> error C7595: 'std::_Basic_format_string<char,const char (&)[13],void *>::_Basic_format_string': call to immediate function is not a constant expression

How can one pass both integers and pointers to integers to be formatted by `std::format`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are seeing has nothing to do with the presence or absence of any `int` arguments amongst the parameters to the call to `std::format`. (Try changing the format string in your first snippet so that it ends with `a4 = {:#010x}` in place of `a4 = {}` and you will see the same error message, there.)

Rather, the error – *albeit cryptic* – occurs because the format specifier you provide is not valid for a pointer argument. The `#` specifer is only valid for integer or floating-point arguments (as also the leading `0` and the trailing `x`?). ([Possibly useful cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter#Standard_format_specification).)

So, in your case, if you want to specify such a format for a pointer value, you should cast that pointer to a suitable *integer* type (`intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` are likely good candidates) rather than to a `void*`:

```cpp
AYAPI_API int AYRenderPrim(int* a1)
{
    Log(std::format("@{}: a1 = {:#010x}", __FUNCTION__, reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(a1)));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It all makes a lot of sense now with your explications :)

Comment: I'm wondering why we can not use static_cast<> instead of reinterpret_cast<>. static_cast<> results in compiler error (using VS2022).

Comment: @Carl You can't `static_cast` between pointer and non-pointer types, because they are unrelated and there is no *implicit* conversion dictated by the Standard (as there is for, say, `int` to `double`). And `intptr_t` is *not* a pointer type, despite its name. (Although maybe casting a pointer to `bool` is an exception?)

Comment: OK, thanks. I think we often "print" memory addresses (so pointers), std::format and related functions should be more helpful for this.